# Cannot upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.3 via composer

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.3

I have a clean Magento 2.2.6 with sample data that I installed using composer.

I am trying to update it to Magento 2.3 so following the steps outlined [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) by the Magento team.

After running `composer update` I get the following:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.2.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[101.0.4, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.5].
    - magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.2.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[101.0.4, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2, 101.0.3, 101.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0, 101.0.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[101.1.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - Installation request for magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.2.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist-sample-data[100.2.0].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the sample data - if you have sample data installed then first run `php bin/magento sampledata:remove`

Thanks to Alan Storm!

Answer (score 8):

First be sure you are running PHP 7.1 or 7.2

Update your composer

run those commandes:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
```

Specify additional packages for composer
Run this

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
```

Remove unused packages

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

Update autoload

Open `composer.json` and edit the `"autoload": "psr-4"` section to include `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"` :

```
"Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
"Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
"Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
```

Apply updates

```
composer update
```

Clear caches and generated content

```
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
```

Update the database schema and data

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Disable maintenance mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Clear the cache, reindex, if you get a server error tray to deploy static content.

and that's all,

You can check the full explanation here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: No additional value. You just copy pasted from the Magento docs

Comment: You just saved my life, was getting dependecy issues with the console:
symfony/dependency-injection v2.5.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.1.0-BETA1].
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most complete answer I've seen on multiple threads, perfectly suiting my issue, thanks !

Comment: Well explained answer. Thanks for the nice post @CDzWebDev.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the steps in the Magento documentation on the page that is specifically for doing a [Command-line upgrade with sample data](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-rc1-samp.html).

Comment: I didn't try it that way - because I had first uninstalled the sample data but thank you for nevertheless pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

After updating Magento to 2.3.0 version, you still available to install sample data.

So, updating process looks like:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:remove
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```