# After upgrade to Magento 2.3 setup:upgrade fails with sample-data installed

Tags: upgrade, sample-data, magento2.3

I've updated two installations from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 without any problems, but next one makes some trouble.

- PHP 7.1.23
- 2.2.6 with plain sample data (no edits made in backend here)

Steps:

- removed sample data from composer.json
- updated to 2.3
- `bin/magento sampledata:deploy`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Quitted with ...

```
...
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly
```

systeml.xml

```
main.ERROR: Sample Data error: Unique constraint violation found [] []
```

When i remove the sample-data `setup:upgrade` works ... Any ideas?

**Edit:**

No4, same steps, worked w/o problem ...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/251704/3024